# Upload file not working

Tags: php, html

I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
Click Browse and choose a file from your PC<br /><br />
<form method="POST" action="_URL_" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="IMGform">
<input type="file" name="image_upload"><br /><br />
<input class="button" type="Submit" value="Change Image">
<input type="hidden" name="add_image" value="true">
</form> 
</body>
```

It simply produces nothing when I add a file to upload.

var_dump($_POST) only produces:

```
array(1) { ["add_image"]=> string(4) "true" }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files are available through [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), not `$_POST`.

See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for further information.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP when files are uploaded, they are accessible via the `$_FILES` superglobal, rather than in the $_POST superglobal.  See [POST Method Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)